# Can remove markers but unable to add in Vue3 Google Maps library

Tags: npm, vuejs3

I'm working on a feature using the Vue 3 Google Maps library where I'm applying filters to control marker visibility. The markers are globally declared using const markers = ref({ blue: [], red: [], gray: [] });. Using the v-for directive, I'm displaying the CustomMarker component based on categories (blue, red, gray). Initially, markers display correctly upon loading, and removing filtered markers from the map also works. However, after removing markers, they don't reappear when trying to add them back. I've ensured that data movement is correct and there are no errors. The problem seems to be with reactivity when adding markers again. Any insights into why this reactivity issue is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

```
~~
        <CustomMarker v-for="marker in markers.blue" :key="marker.no" :options="{position : marker.location}">
          <div><i class="fas fa-location-pin blue"></i></div>
        </CustomMarker>
        <CustomMarker v-for="marker in markers.red" :key="marker.no" :options="{position : marker.location}">
          <div><i class="fas fa-location-pin red"></i></div>
        </CustomMarker>
        <CustomMarker v-for="marker in markers.gray" :key="marker.no" :options="{position : marker.location}">
          <div><i class="fas fa-location-pin gray"></i></div>
        </CustomMarker>
~~

const markers = ref({
    blue: [],
    red: [],
    gray: []
  });
~~
const mergeData = function(wList, wIList){
      let list=[];
      for(let i=0; i<wList.length;i++){
        let val = wList[i];
        let iVal = wIList[i]
        let item = {
          no:val.no,
          location:{lat:val.lat,lng:val.lng},
          name:val.name,
          info:val.info,
          production:iVal.production,
          lastVistDate:iVal.lastVistDate,
          isChecked:iVal.isChecked
        }
        list.push(item);
      }

    //유전정보마커 분류 및 생성
    markers.value.red = [];
    markers.value.blue = [];
    markers.value.gray = [];
    list.forEach(item => {
      if (item.production < 100) {
        markers.value.red.push(item);
      } else if (item.production >= 100 && item.production < 200) {
        markers.value.blue.push(item);
      } else {
        markers.value.gray.push(item);
      }
    });
}
mergeData(wellList.value,wellInfoList.value);
```